# Unable to draw an image on windowless plugin when video is played

Tags: html5-video, firebreath

I am trying to display Video(played by HTML5 video tag) behind a windowless plugin(firebreath). Video was perfectly blended with plugin display (semi-transparent image is drawn) when GPU-acceleration was enabled (using Chrome flags) .

However, Plugin display went for a toss when video is played at present( with chrome flags enabled). Suspecting chromium updates causing this issue.

Similar Question @ [HTML display of Plugin and videotag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20071413/html-display-of-plugin-and-videotag/23606473#23606473)

Any suggestions/work around for me to try out? Please help.

Comment: You might try using the new async drawing stuff; not sure what all browsers support it, but I think there are some docs somewhere

Comment: Taxilin,
Am not sure of Async drawing stuff. However, embed tag solved the video blending using using Quicktime. Do you see any issues with this approach?

Comment: One issue with Quicktime approach is auto play doesn't show video for first time(Yet to find why this happens only with npapi plugin). rest all looks fine. 

Thanks,
Sande

Comment: I have no idea why that would be, so I have no idea whether or not that will have any unexpected problems

Comment: We played video on a Canvas to blend plugin display with Video. This approach works. :)